# Specific alignment in subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage, multirow

If I want to print multiple figures in figure, I'm using subfigure in the figure environment. This work quit well and is looking smart, if all figures have the similar height. Now there is this figure which is more than two times higher than the other ones. I would like to order the subfigures like its shown in the following picture:

[image: Exemplary alignment of subfigures]

But I don’t know how to get this into Latex.

My regular code for four subfigures:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{highone}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c}
    \caption{}
    \label{c}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{d}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Blabla.}
\label{fig:abcd}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: a table with three columns--the first column accommodates fig a--the second and third column accommodate fig b and fig c--below that multicolumn(2) for the last fig d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the subfigures (b), (c) and (d) in another `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[l]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm,width=\textwidth]{a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[r]{0.64\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=20mm,width=\textwidth]{b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=20mm,width=\textwidth]{c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.64\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=20mm,width=\textwidth]{d}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Blabla.}
\label{fig:abcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]