# How to place figures in two columns?

Tags: graphics, multicol

I have five figures and wanna display them in the following manner:
[image]

I am wondering how to do this. I tried to use \begin{multicol} inside \begin{figure} but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do these figures have a referable caption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specific alignment in subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519137/specific-alignment-in-subfigure)

Comment: Are all five images squares? And can it be assumed that the image on the left is as wide as any two images on the right?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/figure-subfigure-layout-with-different-numbers/494135#494135