# subfigure alignment in IEEE double column format

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran, subfig

I am trying to align three figures in the IEEE double column format (see below).
[image]

I have looked for solutions and the [closest one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519154/220520) I found uses the subfigure package. The IEEE latex template uses the subfig package and advises against using the subfigure package. Here is my code which does not output the desired figure. Please note I have deleted a lot from the IEEEtran template, since it has many comments and packages. A full version can be found [here](https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType) for IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% *** SUBFIGURE PACKAGES ***
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\begin{document}
hiiii
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:a} \includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{a}}\\
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:b} \includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{b}}
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:c} \includegraphics[height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{c}}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code fragment to a complete document, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited the question. I don't want to include the entire template because of length but I attached the link.

Comment: Does each of the images need its own sub caption or do you just want to arrange three images as you show in your firts image?

Comment: @leandriis I did not want to include the actual images but each image has a subcaption (a), (b), etc as the code shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is with a `minipage` environment for image 1 and 2.
Note that the minipages are not properly vertically aligned here, the third image is just scaled to a suitable height.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% *** SUBFIGURE PACKAGES ***
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:a}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}\\
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:b}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:c}\includegraphics[height=7.2cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \end{minipage}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be a good idea to remove the whitespace character after each of the three `\label{...}` directives. Plus, do delete the `\centering` directive since it's redundant.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I haved edited the answer. I overlooked the whitespaces.

Comment: @user6360 here, it is set as a portion of `linewidth` in `\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}`; it has the same value for both columns but may be changed individually of course. I did just set height and removed the `keepaspectratio` since only then it looks like your desired output with the strechted image 3. You are free to set any height or also to enable `keepaspectratio` again.